# Step from parameter to page (Xamarin App)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, parameters, xamarin.forms

I am developing a PCL App In Xamarin ... and I want to pass a variable from one page to another ... the variable is "usersMovil", although in the method constructor MenuPage (UsuariosMovil usuariosMovil) is mapped .... when it leaves Is no longer available and considers it null ....I want to pass from LoginPage ----> MenuPage.... any help for me?

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    enterButton.Clicked += enterButton_Clicked;
}

private async void enterButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEntry.Text))
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe Ingresar un Usuario", "Aceptar");
        userEntry.Focus();
        return;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordEntry.Text))
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe Ingresar un Usuario", "Aceptar");
        userEntry.Focus();
        return;
    }

    waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
    string result;
    try
    {
        enterButton.IsEnabled = false;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://200.27.70.5/web_sit2/");
        string url = string.Format("api/UsuariosMovilsAPI/{0}/{1}", userEntry.Text, passwordEntry.Text);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        enterButton.IsEnabled = true;
        waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "No hay Conexión...", "Aceptar");
        enterButton.IsEnabled = true;
        waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        return;
    }

    waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (result) || result == "null")
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Usuarios y/o Password NO válido", "Aceptar");
        passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        passwordEntry.Focus();
        return;
    }

    var usuariosMovil = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuariosMovil>(result);
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(usuariosMovil));
}
```

A WebServices is in charge of bringing the User and Password that was entered into the system, the idea is to pass those variables between pages, but in the `event infractionButton_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)`, the variable `usersMovil` is taken and takes the value `null`.

```
public UsuariosMovil usuariosMovil;
public int UsuarioMovilID;

public MenuPage(UsuariosMovil usuarioMovil)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    UsuarioMovilID = usuarioMovil.UsuarioMovilID;

    titleLabel.Text = string.Format("Bienvenid@ {0} {1}", usuarioMovil.Nombre, usuarioMovil.Apellido);

    infraccionButton.Clicked += infraccionButton_Clicked;
    consultarButton.Clicked += consultarButton_Clicked;
    actualizarButton.Clicked += actualizarButton_Clicked;
}

private async void actualizarButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ActualizarPage());
}

private async void consultarButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ConsultarPage());
}

private async void infraccionButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewInfraccionPage(usuariosMovil));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpointer in the constructor of your menupage to see if you get any value there?

Comment: Yes, it gives me the values ​​I want ... the problem is when I exit the constructor .... in the line await Navigation.PushAsync (new NewInfraccionPage (usuariosMovil)) .... the variable usersMovil takes the value null  @JordyDieltjens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your problem. You forgot your variabele named usuarioMovil in your constructor of your menupage.

Just add following line:
this.usuarioMovil = usuarioMovil;

I hope that solves your problem ;)